# HDFS rack awareness strategy for replication factor other than default replication factor i.e 3

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

As per what I have read about rack awareness with default replication factor i.e 3, "We have one replica on one rack and other two replicas on another rack", however my question is,

What if I have different replication factor let's say '5' for a certain file and total number of racks in my hadoop cluster are '3' , in such scenario how the Rack awareness will work ?

Comment: Works the same. After the second replica, racks are picked at random

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I am still confused, because hadoop will try to distribute the data as much as possible and it'll also consider the communication cost between the available racks. I might be wrong but I feel if it places data randomly it might ignore either 'distribution of data' Or 'the cost of communication'. Are there any calculations on basis of which hadoop will decide the replica placement between racks and if there are such calculations I would like to know them.

Comment: First a rack is selected, then two replicas are in that rack, different nodes, from what I recall, remaining replicas are placed randomly, but the logic might consistently place blocks in pairs into racks